# How to display image in HTML5 Canvas at runtime in MVC5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, asp.net-mvc-5

I could display image at runtime in ASP.net Web Forms using generic web handler (.ashx). But I could not find a way to display image at runtime in MVC 5.
Here is what I am doing:-

View:-

```
 <section class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 img-thumbnail">
            <canvas class="col-md-12" id="canImageDisplay" width="800px"> </canvas>
        </section>
```

Controller:-

```
byte[] Img = ........;
model.Image = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(Img);
return View(model);
```

Script:-

```
<script>
    var $canImg = document.getElementById("canImageDisplay");
    var $ctx = $canImg.getContext('2d');
    var $img = new Image();
    $img.onload = function () {
        $ctx.drawImage($img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    };
    $img.src = @Model.Image;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have typos:**

```
// not img.width & img.height without the $

$ctx.drawImage($img, 0, 0, $img.width, $img.height);
```

**Accessing your dataURL in JavaScript**

You're trying to pass the dataURL in your Model and then trying to get javascript to access the Model. You can't do that directly, but you can do it indirectly by fetching the model from the raw html and encoding it.

```
var vm = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
var dataURL=vm.Image;
```

A more common way is to **set up a controller method** that returns your dataURL as a result.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    ...

    public string getDataURL()
    {
        string dataURL = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo...
        return (dataURL);
    }

    ...

}
```

When your javascript needs the dataURL, **have javascript fetch it directly with `$.ajax`**.

```
$.get('/Home/getDataURL', null, function (d) {
    var dataURL=d;
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 150, 0);
    }
    img.src = dataURL;
});
```